# SSH passphrase wish.exe

Tags: angular, ssh, openssh, angular-cli-ghpages

I'm trying to generate a Ghpages for an angular app.
When I push my work `$ git push origin branch-name` on the repo, my passphrase is asked IN the GIT WINDOW there is NO problem.

But when I try to generate a ghpage `$ ng build --base-href=repo-name` , another window opens "OpenSSH" and asks me for my passphrase and of course it is not valid. This window has the following location `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\wish.exe`

Usually this window does not open when I do a *pull* and *push*.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by following these instructions :

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows

Hopefully this will help some people.

Thanks to github docs and myself!